# Why is there a memory leak on SinglyLinkedList deletion?

Tags: c++, class, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

I have a utility library that I developed and noticed I have a memory leak in the SinglyLinkedList class. After debugging the code, I could not find why I have a memory leak. This is the test case I am using in the `main` function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SinglyLinkedList.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Program operating..." << endl;
    

    do {
        SinglyLinkedList<int> list = SinglyLinkedList<int>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(1);
        list.add(1);
    } while (true);

    cout << "Program terminated..." << endl;
}
```

Here is `SinglyLinkedList.h` file. It contains the `SinglyLinkedNode` and `SinglyLinkedList` class.

```
#pragma once

// SinglyLinkedNode
template <class T>
class SinglyLinkedNode {
public:
    T data;
    SinglyLinkedNode<T>* nextNode;

    SinglyLinkedNode(T data);
    SinglyLinkedNode(const SinglyLinkedNode& singlyLinkedNode);

    void operator = (const SinglyLinkedNode& singlyLinkedNode);

    ~SinglyLinkedNode();
};

template <class T>
SinglyLinkedNode<T>::SinglyLinkedNode(T data) {
    this->data = data;
    nextNode = nullptr;
}

template <class T>
SinglyLinkedNode<T>::SinglyLinkedNode(const SinglyLinkedNode& singlyLinkedNode) {
    this->data = singlyLinkedNode.data;
    nextNode = nullptr;
}

template <class T>
void SinglyLinkedNode<T>::operator = (const SinglyLinkedNode& singlyLinkedNode) {
    this->data = singlyLinkedNode.data;
    nextNode = nullptr;
}

template <class T>
SinglyLinkedNode<T>::~SinglyLinkedNode() {
    nextNode = nullptr;
}

// SinglyLinkedList
template <class E>
class SinglyLinkedList {
private:
    unsigned int size;
public:
    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* head;
    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* tail;

    SinglyLinkedList();
    SinglyLinkedList(const SinglyLinkedList& singlyLinkedList);     // O(n)

    void operator = (const SinglyLinkedList<E> singlyLinkedList);   // O(n)

    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* add(E data);                       // O(1)
    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* addAt(unsigned int i, E data);     // O(n)
    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* addToHead(E data);                 // O(1)
    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* addToTail(E data);                 // O(n)

    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* getNodeAt(unsigned int i);         // O(n)
    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* getHeadNode();                     // O(1)
    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* getTailNode();                     // O(1)
    bool contains(SinglyLinkedNode<E>* singlyLinkedNode);   // O(n)

    E getDataAt(unsigned int i);                            // O(n)
    E getHeadData();                                        // O(1)
    E getTailData();                                        // O(1)
    bool contains(E data);                                  // O(n)

    E remove(E data);                                       // O(n)
    E removeAt(unsigned int i);                             // O(n)
    E removeHead();                                         // O(1)
    E removeTail();                                         // O(size)

    void clear();                                           // O(size)
    bool isEmpty();                                         // O(1)
    unsigned int getSize();                                 // O(1)

    ~SinglyLinkedList();
};

template <class E>
SinglyLinkedList<E>::SinglyLinkedList() {
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    size = 0;
}

template <class E>
SinglyLinkedList<E>::SinglyLinkedList(const SinglyLinkedList<E>& singlyLinkedList) {
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    size = 0;

    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* currentNode = singlyLinkedList.head;
    while (currentNode != nullptr) {
        addToTail(currentNode->data);
        currentNode = currentNode->nextNode;
    }
}

template <class E>
void SinglyLinkedList<E>::operator = (const SinglyLinkedList<E> singlyLinkedList) {
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    size = 0;

    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* currentNode = singlyLinkedList.head;
    while (currentNode != nullptr) {
        addToTail(currentNode->data);
        currentNode = currentNode->nextNode;
    }
}

template <class E>
SinglyLinkedNode<E>* SinglyLinkedList<E>::add(E data) {
    return addToTail(data);
}

template <class E>
SinglyLinkedNode<E>* SinglyLinkedList<E>::addAt(unsigned int i, E data) {
    if (i > size)
        return nullptr;
    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* singlyLinkedNode = new SinglyLinkedNode<E>(data);
    if (size == 0) {
        head = singlyLinkedNode;
        tail = singlyLinkedNode;
        size++;
        return singlyLinkedNode;
    }
    if (i == 0) {
        singlyLinkedNode->nextNode = head;
        head = singlyLinkedNode;
        size++;
        return singlyLinkedNode;
    }
    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* currentNode = head;
    for (unsigned int j = 1; j < i; j++)
        currentNode = currentNode->nextNode;
    singlyLinkedNode->nextNode = currentNode->nextNode;
    currentNode->nextNode = singlyLinkedNode;
    size++;
    return singlyLinkedNode;
}

template <class E>
SinglyLinkedNode<E>* SinglyLinkedList<E>::addToHead(E data) {
    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* singlyLinkedNode = new SinglyLinkedNode<E>(data);
    if (size == 0) {
        head = singlyLinkedNode;
        tail = singlyLinkedNode;
        size++;
        return singlyLinkedNode;
    }
    singlyLinkedNode->nextNode = head;
    head = singlyLinkedNode;
    size++;
    return singlyLinkedNode;
}

template <class E>
SinglyLinkedNode<E>* SinglyLinkedList<E>::addToTail(E data) {
    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* singlyLinkedNode = new SinglyLinkedNode<E>(data);
    if (size == 0) {
        head = singlyLinkedNode;
        tail = singlyLinkedNode;
        size++;
        return singlyLinkedNode;
    }
    tail->nextNode = new SinglyLinkedNode<E>(data);
    tail = tail->nextNode;
    size++;
    return singlyLinkedNode;
}

template <class E>
SinglyLinkedNode<E>* SinglyLinkedList<E>::getNodeAt(unsigned int i) {
    if (size == 0 || i >= size)
        return nullptr;
    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* currentNode = head;
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        currentNode = currentNode->nextNode;
    return currentNode;
}

template <class E>
SinglyLinkedNode<E>* SinglyLinkedList<E>::getHeadNode() {
    return head;
}

template <class E>
SinglyLinkedNode<E>* SinglyLinkedList<E>::getTailNode() {
    return tail;
}

template <class E>
bool SinglyLinkedList<E>::contains(SinglyLinkedNode<E>* singlyLinkedNode) {
    SinglyLinkedList<E>* currentNode = head;
    while (currentNode != nullptr)
        if (currentNode == singlyLinkedNode)
            return true;
    return false;
}

template <class E>
E SinglyLinkedList<E>::getDataAt(unsigned int i) {
    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* singlyLinkedNode = getNodeAt(i);
    if (singlyLinkedNode == nullptr)
        throw 0;
    return singlyLinkedNode->data;
}

template <class E>
E SinglyLinkedList<E>::getHeadData() {
    if (head == nullptr)
        throw 1;
    return head->data;
}

template <class E>
E SinglyLinkedList<E>::getTailData() {
    if (tail == nullptr)
        throw 2;
    return tail->data;
}

template <class E>
bool SinglyLinkedList<E>::contains(E data) {
    if (size == 0)
        return false;
    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* currentNode = head;
    while (currentNode != nullptr) {
        if (currentNode->data == data)
            return true;
        currentNode = currentNode->nextNode;
    }
    return false;
}

template <class E>
E SinglyLinkedList<E>::remove(E data) {
    if (size == 0)
        throw 3;
    if (head->data == data)
        return removeHead();
    if (size > 1) {
        SinglyLinkedNode<E>* currentNode = head;
        while (currentNode->nextNode != nullptr) {
            if (currentNode->nextNode->data == data) {
                E data = currentNode->nextNode->data;
                SinglyLinkedNode<E>* nodeToDelete = currentNode->nextNode;
                if (nodeToDelete == tail)
                    tail = currentNode;
                currentNode->nextNode = currentNode->nextNode->nextNode;
                delete(nodeToDelete);
                size--;
                return data;
            }
            currentNode = currentNode->nextNode;
        }
    }
    throw 4;
}

template <class E>
E SinglyLinkedList<E>::removeAt(unsigned int i) {
    if (size == 0 || i >= size)
        throw 5;
    if (i == 0)
        return removeHead();
    if (i == (size - 1))
        return removeTail();

    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* currentNode = head;
    for (unsigned int j = 1; j < i; j++)
        currentNode = currentNode->nextNode;
    E data = currentNode->nextNode->data;
    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* nodeToDelete = currentNode->nextNode;
    currentNode->nextNode = currentNode->nextNode->nextNode;
    delete(nodeToDelete);
    size--;
    return data;
}

template <class E>
E SinglyLinkedList<E>::removeHead() {
    if (size == 0)
        throw 6;
    if (size == 1) {
        E data = head->data;
        delete(head);
        size--;
        head = nullptr;
        tail = nullptr;
        return data;
    }
    if (size == 2) {
        E data = head->data;
        SinglyLinkedNode<E>* newHead = head->nextNode;
        delete(head);
        head = newHead;
        tail = newHead;
        size--;
        return data;
    }
    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* newHead = head->nextNode;
    E data = head->data;
    delete head;
    head = newHead;
    size--;
    return data;
}

template <class E>
E SinglyLinkedList<E>::removeTail() {
    if (size == 0)
        throw 7;
    if (size == 1)
        return removeHead();
    if (size == 2) {
        E data = tail->data;
        delete(tail);
        tail = head;
        size--;
        return data;
    }

    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* currentNode = head;
    while (currentNode->nextNode->nextNode != nullptr)
        currentNode = currentNode->nextNode;
    E data = tail->data;
    delete(tail);
    currentNode->nextNode = nullptr;
    tail = currentNode;
    size--;
    return data;
}

template <class E>
void SinglyLinkedList<E>::clear() {
    while (size > 0)
        removeHead();
}

template <class E>
bool SinglyLinkedList<E>::isEmpty() {
    if (size == 0)
        return true;
}

template <class E>
unsigned int SinglyLinkedList<E>::getSize() {
    return size;
}

template <class E>
SinglyLinkedList<E>::~SinglyLinkedList() {
    clear();
}
```

The memory leak only asserts when I have more than one node in the list. I tried going step by step using the debugger, but everything seems to be working fine. Any leads would be very helpful.

Comment: In `addToTail`, `singlyLinkedNode` is unused if size is > 0. Instead, you create a completely new node that is added to the list.

Comment: You are right! Such a big problem over something so little. Thank you very much. I am going to review my other data structures. Feel free to look at them over here https://github.com/InTimeTechnologies/Utility

Comment: Removing from a list with 2 items and a longer list is the same problem, don't special case them. The tail already points at the second item in that case.

Comment: If you make `tail` a `SinglyLinkedNode<E>** tail{&head};` a lot of the code becomes simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in this function

```
template <class E>
SinglyLinkedNode<E>* SinglyLinkedList<E>::addToTail(E data) {
    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* singlyLinkedNode = new SinglyLinkedNode<E>(data);
    if (size == 0) {
        head = singlyLinkedNode;
        tail = singlyLinkedNode;
        size++;
        return singlyLinkedNode;
    }
    tail->nextNode = new SinglyLinkedNode<E>(data);
    tail = tail->nextNode;
    size++;
    return singlyLinkedNode;
}
```

called by the function `add`

```
template <class E>
SinglyLinkedNode<E>* SinglyLinkedList<E>::add(E data) {
    return addToTail(data);
}
```

there is a memory leak.

A new node is allocated twice when the list is not empty

```
SinglyLinkedNode<E>* singlyLinkedNode = new SinglyLinkedNode<E>(data);
```

and

```
tail->nextNode = new SinglyLinkedNode<E>(data);
```

And the allocated node pointed to by the pointer `singlyLinkedNode` is not deleted.

There is other problematic code in your program. For example the parameter of the assignment operator

```
void operator = (const SinglyLinkedList<E> singlyLinkedList);
```

should be a reference. Otherwise the operator will be inefficient because it will create a new temporary list.

And moreover it also produces numerous memory leaks because it does not clear the current list.

```
template <class E>
void SinglyLinkedList<E>::operator = (const SinglyLinkedList<E> singlyLinkedList) {
    head = nullptr;
    tail = nullptr;
    size = 0;

    SinglyLinkedNode<E>* currentNode = singlyLinkedList.head;
    while (currentNode != nullptr) {
        addToTail(currentNode->data);
        currentNode = currentNode->nextNode;
    }
}
```

You need to revise your entire program.:)

Comment: You are right and on point about everything. I know what you pinpointed must be the way you stated. I don't know what I did not write it as such. I have to be more careful next time. Also, your second sighting helped spot another function that makes use of that ```void operator =``` function. I commented ```// Contains memory leak``` and refrained from using it until it was fixed. I can now use it again thanks to that. I appreciate your post very much. I marked your response as "accepted answer".